# Is it idiomatic in go to handle all returned errors?

Tags: go, error-handling

Many functions in go return errors to fit an interface, but these errors are always nil. Should these errors still be checked?

An example for this is the [crypto/sha1 Write() function](https://golang.org/src/crypto/sha1/sha1.go?s=1064:1418), which does not set the err value. So the code does not need to be:

```
_, err = sha1Hasher.Write(buffer)
if err != nil {
    log.Printf("sha1 could not be calculated (%s)", err)
}
```

but only:

```
sha1Hasher.Write(buffer)
```

The second option is shorter and cleaner and go is a lot about simple code but it is suggested to handle all errors:

> But remember: Whatever you do, always check your errors!

https://blog.golang.org/errors-are-values

> Clearly, we must handle any errors; we can't just ignore them.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/16126516/4944254

Which is the best way to go?

Comment: You don't need to handle errors that can't happen, or couldn't be handled. The `digest.Write` methods only returns an error to conform to the `io.Writer` interface. You usually won't see anyone checking the errors from `fmt.Println` either.

Comment: this is a good reading for you http://dave.cheney.net/2016/04/27/dont-just-check-errors-handle-them-gracefully

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In situation that you described, you will probably be fine with not checking error, same as not checking errors when using `fmt.Println`.

However, when you use `fmt.Println` you know which concrete implementations are being used. When you are using `Writer` interface (which `os.Stdout` implements) - you can not assume if implementation will return any errors. In that case, IMHO, you should always check errors.

Btw, writing to `os.Stdout`, which `fmt.Print` uses, can fail (one might be able to replace value of `os.Stdout` to something else).