# Less verbose error handling in Go?

Tags: go

I have some Go code that queries a Database using the "database/sql" package. Most of these functions return: `result, err` or `rows, err`.

Because of this, you end up with many repetitive blocks like this:

```
if err != nil {
  // Handle Error
}
```

I've seen "cleaner" code for functions that only return err:

```
if err := SomeFunc(); err != nil {
  // Handle Error
}
```

I can't do this with these functions because the variable gets trapped in the scope when I need to access it in another query function later on.

Is there a way to clean up this go code?

Comment: Tangential: if you use [sqlx](https://github.com/jmoiron/sqlx), you can use Get() and Select() to pull, respectively, a single entry or a slice of entries without having to handle a `rows` variable.  Those functions return only an error, and thus work well with the `if <statement>; <conditional> {` style.  sqlx is also just a really amazing library in general.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Handling multiple errors in go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16126102/handling-multiple-errors-in-go)

Answer (score 4):

They're only trapped in scope if they're declared in the `if` block using `:=`. If you declare them outside the `if`, they're in the outer scope:

```
var err error
var result SomeResultType
if result,err = SomeFunc(); err != nil {
    // Handle error
}
// Do something with result (or error if you want)
```

Comment: Though in this case, simply moving the function call outside the if statement (and using shortform declaration) is actually a more compact code style.  Declaring the vars beforehand added 2 lines when moving the statement into the if block saved 1 line.  Can work rather well if the vars are already declared for some reason or if you use named returns, though.

Comment: Either way, it has the same effect of moving the declaration outside the block.