# Go Error Handling when Returning Structs

Tags: error-handling, go

As far as I can tell(from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16963298/golang-error-handling-techniques), and from reading the standerd library), the idomatic way of handling errors in a library returning both your data and an error.

The question is, when I do run have to return an error, what do I return as my data? An empty struct? 0?

Here is an example

```
// Load the config
func LoadConfig(location string) (Config, error) {
    // Read the file
    configFile, err := ioutil.ReadFile(location)
    if err != nil {
        return Config{}, err
    }

    // Convert it to Config struct
    var config Config
    json.Unmarshal(configFile, &config)
    return config, nil
}
```

Is this idiomatic?

Comment: Besides your question (there's already a good answer), one thing to note - in your example you should also return the error from `json.Unmarshal`, of course.

Comment: @Not_a_Golfer Thanks, I missed that one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends on the context. You can return the empty value for the corresponding type or `nil` if the returned type is a pointer. But you could also return partial result together with the error if that makes sense for the function. For example in `bufio` package `Reader.ReadString` returns string and error. The [docs state](https://golang.org/src/pkg/bufio/bufio.go#L408):

> If ReadString encounters an error before finding a delimiter, it returns the data read before the error and the error itself (often io.EOF).

Comment: Thanks, that was what I was thinking.