# Does Go have standard Err variables?

Tags: go

Just started using Golang. I think that it is idiomatic to declare an error variable and use it in your error structure to determine what went wrong, as is done in [strconv.go](https://golang.org/src/strconv/atoi.go). There, `ErrRange` and `ErrSyntax` is declared, and when appropriate, references to those are stored in `NumError` structs when they return. I think that the reason is because then the address of the reference to the error stored in `NumError` can be compared with the `ErrRange` and `ErrSyntax` variables to determine which type of error was returned.

Are there "standard" such declared error types? In Java, for example, you have things like `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException`. Is there, for instance, `ErrArgument` or `ErrUnsupportedOperation` that I can use in my own code instead of creating new error variables that mean the same thing every time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there aren't. Just provide intelligible errors instead of generic ones. What information does a IllegalArgument transport? Not much, not enough.

Comment: Usually, even when I'm writing Python which has Java-like exception categories, my *intent* is to handle either a specific error I know I want a special path for (like a network error calling some outside API, say), or to catch anything at all (and, e.g., log and abort). So potentially-special-snowflake error values mostly work. The `os` package does provide functions that categorize its own errors (e.g., `os.IsPermission(err error) bool`), but that's sort of a different thing.

Answer (score 34):

There are a few common idiomatic ways for a package author to make error returns.

1. Fixed error variables, usually named `Err…`

   ```
   var (
           ErrSomethingBad = errors.New("some string")
           ErrKindFoo      = errors.New("foo happened")
   )
   ```
2. Error types, usually named `…Error`

   ```
   type SomeError struct {
        // extra information, whatever might be useful to callers
        // (or for making a nice message in `Error()`)
        ExtraInfo int
   }
   type OtherError string

   func (e SomeError) Error() string { /* … */ }
   func (e OtherError) Error() string {
           return fmt.Sprintf("failure doing something with %q", string(e))
   }
   ```

   With Go 1.13 and later you may also want to implement a `Unwrap() error` method for use with [`errors.Unwrap`](https://golang.org/pkg/errors#Unwrap).
3. Ad hoc `errors.New` values as needed.

   ```
   func SomepackageFunction() error {
           return errors.New("not implemented")
   }
   ```
4. Using errors defined in the standard packages. Usually limited to a small set such as `io.EOF`; in most cases it's better to create your own via method 1 above.

   ```
   func SomeFunc() error {
           return io.EOF
   }
   ```

   Note that sometimes when implementing an interface (such as a `Read` method to become an `io.Reader`) it *is* best to use matching errors (or "required" by the specification of the interface).
5. Making an interface such as [`net.Error`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/#Error):

   ```
   type Error interface {
       error
       Timeout() bool   // Is the error a timeout?
       Temporary() bool // Is the error temporary?
   }
   ```
6. With Go 1.13 or later, returning an existing error with simple context (for more complicated context, use a custom error type with an `Unwrap()` method):

   ```
   func SomepackageFunction() error {
       err := somethingThatCanFail()
       if err != nil {
               return fmt.Errorf("some context: %w", err)
       }
   }
   ```

   Note the new (to Go 1.13) formatting verb `%w`, it wraps the provided error so that callers can get at it with `errors.Unwrap` or `error.Is`.

Often you'll use a mix of all these ways.

The first, second, and fifth are preferred if you think *any* user of your package will *ever* want to test for specific errors.
They allow things like:

```
err := somepkg.Function()
if err == somepkg.ErrSomethingBad {
        // …
}
// or for an error type, something like:
if e, ok := err.(somepkg.SomeError); ok && e.ExtraInfo > 42 {
        // use the fields/methods of `e` if needed
}
```

For Go 1.13 or later, the above can instead be written as:

```
err := somepkg.Function()
if errors.Is(err, somepkg.ErrSomethingBad) {
        // …
}
// or for an error type, something like:
var someErr somepkg.SomeError
if errors.As(err, &someErr) && someErr.ExtraInfo > 42 {
        // use the fields/methods of `someErr` if needed
}
```

the difference is that errors will be unwrapped as needed.

The fifth way (which is just an extension of the second) allows checking the error for behaviour/type like so (or using Go 1.13's `errors.As`):

```
if e, ok := err.(net.Error); ok && e.Timeout() {
        // it's a timeout, sleep and retry
}
```

The problem with the third way is it leaves no sane way for a user of the package to test for it. (Testing the contents of the string returned by `err.Error()` isn't a great idea).
However, it's fine for the errors that you don't ever expect anyone to want to test for.

Further reading:

- [Effective Go on errors](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#errors)
- The Go Blog [Error handling and Go](https://blog.golang.org/error-handling-and-go)
- Dave Cheney [Inspecting Errors](http://dave.cheney.net/2014/12/24/inspecting-errors)
- Peter Bourgon [Programming with errors](https://peter.bourgon.org/blog/2019/09/11/programming-with-errors.html)

Answer (score 2):

As you have seen, there are specific errors that specific packages use.  For example, in the [database/sql](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/) package, they define:

```
var ErrNoRows = errors.New("sql: no rows in result set")
```

So if you do `QueryRow` (which defers the error until `Scan`), and then `Scan`, you can do

```
if  err := row.Scan(&data); err != nil && err != sql.ErrNoRows {
    //something actually went wrong
} else if err != nil {
    //no results
} else {
    //we found it
}
```

[os/exec](https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/) has `var ErrNotFound = errors.New("executable file not found in $PATH")`

[encoding/json](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/) has a `type UnmarshalTypeError` which is just a type that implements the `error` interface.

So no, while there is no "set of standard errors", you can (and most likely should) have specific error variables that you reuse.

You could have your own errorMsgs package that you use, where you can reuse common errors:

```
err := doSomething(); if err != nil {
    switch err {
        case errorMsgs.IllegalArgument:
           //do something
        case errorMsgs.CouldNotConnect:
           //do something else
     }
}
```