# Finegrained error handling based on error type in Go

Tags: go, error-handling, try-catch

TLDR: There is a function in some library, which does something over network and may fail with error. Error may indicate bad input parameter, invalid credentials, network failure... And... I don't know what else. And that's the question.

How do I know, what errors to expect, to handle, say, network failures properly.

Long version:
It is a very common way to handle errors like that in Go code

```
function f0() (v Value, err Error) {
  v2, err := f3()
  if err != nil {
    return
  }

  v1, err := f2(v2)
  if err != nil {
    return
  }

  v, err = f1(v1)
  return
}
```

It is also very common in Go code to not document type of error returned. 
Let's not forget about another common idiom in Go

```
err = errors.New("Boo! I failed") // returns trivial errorString
```

This leads to the situation where caller of `f0()` can get dozens of errors (if `f3()` to `f1()` in my example also do some calls) which represent conceptually different issues.

How to differentiate between all those errors?

Answer (score 0):

Anything implementing this minimal interface is an error;

```
type error interface {
    Error() string
}
```

The easy solution is;

```
type BadCredsError string

func (e BadCredsError) Error() string {
      return string(e)
}
```

Basically, just define your own types and then you can use a type switch or type assertion to determine the specific error types like you see in more OO languages such as C# and Java.

By the way, my sample is like a 2 seconds pseudo code snippet. The go blog discusses far more in depth here; http://blog.golang.org/error-handling-and-go

Comment: Thanks. That's fine if I design my own library. But what if I already use some library? Should I just admit, that the library is poorly designed and fix it by myself? 
The problem, is that such code is VERY common in Go world.

Comment: @edio yep, you're gonna have to get used it. If libraries in C# just threw `new Exception("error string goes here")` then it would be the same situation, the authors just choose to use things like `InvaidOperationException` instead. Usually people use `string.contains` to identify errors in Go. It is convention, not enforced, most libraries follow it.

Comment: See [my answer to another question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30178766/55504) for some more error techniques. IMO if a library/package doesn't do something sensible for errors it produces (at least the ones that it's reasonable code may want to check/handle) then its API is at best incomplete and you should file an issue against the library.

Comment: Note that in `BadCredsError.Error()` method you can't convert `e` to `string` as `e` is a pointer. You have to do: `string(*e)`.

Comment: @icza true. I changed the receiving type. Edio - Ultimately, where the error data is contained doesn't matter. All that matters is that it's consistent. Communicating that information with the type itself does nothing to guarantee consistency. If your library has bad errors, you're stuck. If it doesn't then you should just get over the notion that you need a different type to identify a different error and do some basic string matching. Honestly, strongly typed errors is just over-engineering to try and compensate for poor/inconsistent developers. They add no real value.

Comment: @evanmcdonnal "and do some basic string matching".  Groking around in error strings is fragile and broken. It's not a sane way to determine the source/reason of an error.