# Handling errors from base64 decode in Go

Tags: go, error-handling, base64

Consider this simple base64 decode snippet:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "encoding/base64"
)

func main() {
    const encoded string = "aGVsbG8=" // hello
    decoded, err := base64.StdEncoding.DecodeString(encoded)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(string(decoded))
}
```

This produces *hello* as expected.
Now, if i intentionally pass in corrupt input, e.g.

```
const encoded string = "XXXXXaGVsbG8="
```

then i hit the panic line which gives me:

```
panic: illegal base64 data at input byte 11

goroutine 1 [running]:
main.main()
    /tmp/sandbox422941756/main.go:12 +0x140
```

Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/10290) and [this issue](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/10290), seems there is not much to go by here other than matching the string literal and returning a more meaningful error message to the caller:

```
if err != nil {
    if strings.Contains(err.Error(), "illegal base64 data at input byte") {
        panic("\nbase64 input is corrupt, check service Key")
    }
}
```

There has to be a more elegant way to do this other than string matching.
What is the **go**-esque way to achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look at the error type. For example,

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/base64"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    encoded := "XXXXXaGVsbG8=" // corrupt
    decoded, err := base64.StdEncoding.DecodeString(encoded)
    if err != nil {
        if _, ok := err.(base64.CorruptInputError); ok {
            panic("\nbase64 input is corrupt, check service Key")
        }
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(string(decoded))
}
```

Output:

```
panic: 
base64 input is corrupt, check service Key
```

Comment: Ah yes, definitely, errors have types in Go. I guess read manual first, ask questions later. Thanks!

Comment: Modern Go provides a simpler way to detect whether an error is a certain error - `errors.Is` (https://pkg.go.dev/errors#Is).

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the implementation (unexported `base64.Encoding.decode()` method), if that method returns an error, it can only be of concrete type [`base64.CorruptInputError`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/base64/#CorruptInputError). This error type always produces the following error string:

```
func (e CorruptInputError) Error() string {
    return "illegal base64 data at input byte " + strconv.FormatInt(int64(e), 10)
}
```

So beside some extreme circumstances (like out of memory error, modified execution code etc.) if `base64.StdEncoding.DecodeString()` returns an error, its error string will **always** contain the string `"illegal base64 data at input byte "` (in the current version).

It's needless to check its error string, you can treat any non-`nil` returned error as the input being invalid. And the error string is an implementation detail, so you shouldn't rely on it anyway. The error string is for *humans*, not for *code*. This is how the `encoding/base64` package is implemented, you can't do any finer error handling beside this (and usually there is no need to distinguish separate error cases in case of `Encoding.DecodeString()`).

When a package does give distinct error values for different error cases, there are techniques to handle them well. For details, check out this question:

[Does go have standard Err variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30177860/does-go-have-standard-err-variables/30178766#30178766)

As mentioned, in case of the `encoding/base64` package a value of the concrete `base64.CorruptInputError` type is returned, you can use [type assertion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions) to check for that. See peterSO's answer for that.

Comment: You are relying on a particular implementation at a particular point in time. Don't do that.