# How can I generate multiple URL paths with cherrypy?

Tags: python, url, cherrypy

I feel like I'm running into a brick wall, as I'm not getting anywhere with this, and I believe, simple task.

I'm trying to generate a URL by the likes of '/path/to/url', but upon gazing at multiple StackOverflow Q&A's, the official documentation for cherrypy, I still cannot seem to wrap my head around the issue.

Here's my code so far:

```
import details
import input_checker as input
import time

import cherrypy

class Index(object):

    @cherrypy.expose
    def input(self):
        return input.check_input()

    @cherrypy.expose
    def stream(self):
        while True:
            return 'Hey'
            #return input.check_input()
            time.sleep(3)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    index = Index()
    cherrypy.tree.mount(index.stream(), '/input/stream', {})
    cherrypy.config.update(
        {'server.socket_host': '0.0.0.0'})
    cherrypy.quickstart(index)
```

So essentially, I want to be able to visit http://127.0.0.1:8080/input/stream, and I will be returned with the given result.

After executing this code, and multiple variants of it, I'm still being returned with a 404 not found error, and I'm not sure what I need to do, in order to get it working.

Any tips and/or supporting documentation that I may have skimmed over?

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there are couple problems here, why do you use `MethodDispatcher` do you actually need it?

To serve you `stream` function on `/input/stream` you have to mount it as such:

```
cherrypy.tree.mount(index.stream(), '/input/stream', your_config)
```

note `/input/stream` instead of `/stream`.

But because you're using `MethodDispatcher` this will likely make your endpoint return 405 as GET is not allowed on this endpoint - to fix that just remove the `MethodDispatcher` bit.

But if you do require `MethodDispatcher` you will have to refactor a bit to something like that:

```
class Stream:
    exposed = True # to let cherrypy know that we're exposing all methods in this one

    def GET(self):
        return something

stream = Stream()
cherrypy.tree.mount(stream , '/index/stream',
    {'/':
        {'request.dispatch': cherrypy.dispatch.MethodDispatcher()}
    }
)
```

Also make sure to not actually call your methods when mounting them into cherrypy tree, just pass in the name of the function/class

Comment: Sorry, I'm not meant to be using MethodDispatcher. I'm not sure exactly what it means (I did go through all the tutorials), but I guess I'll have to brush up more on it. Anyhow, I've mounted the method, but I'm not sure what to put for `your_config`, because I don't have one. I've edited my question to the current code that I have.

Comment: @juiceb0xk empty config should do, so just put `{}` in there, and do `index.stream` instead of `index.stream()`

Comment: Awesome, it works. I can sort of correlate this information with the official docs. Thanks for the prompt information :)

Comment: @user3012759 you just deleted a good question (golang), the answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16963298/go-error-handling-techniques#comment98068295_52314410