# golang: cannot recover from Out Of Memory crash

Tags: go

Under certain circumstances, calling append() triggers an out of memory panic and it seems append() itself doesn't return nil.

How could I avoid that panic scenario and show to my user "Resource temporary unavailable" ?

Best regards,

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't.

If the runtime can't allocate memory for append, it may not be able to recover, or communicate "Resource temporary unavailable" to the user. For example, GC might need to allocate to clean up, or the scheduler might be trying to allocate a new thread. Because there's no way to strictly control allocations in a Go program, there's no way to gracefully handle running out of memory.

All OOM conditions terminate a Go program.

Comment: This question makes me curious, there must be some way to handle this more gracefully. What about preemptively checking the systems memory conditions and giving the warning before you get to the point of panic?

Comment: @evanmcdonnal: How would you preemptively check? What you consider "used" may not be what kernel considers used. You can't rely on malloc's return, because it always gives you a pointer when overcommit is on. The kernel may also free up memory for you when needed, causing the "check" to return false positives. (and that's just on Linux, you'd have to make this cross-platform)

Comment: I'm not sure, it was just an idea for how to improve the application. If I knew of a package that could reliably tell me where my memory usage was relative to the maximum I'm allowed by the runtime then I would have used it to write an answer attempting what I described. There may be no reliable way to do it. However, I personally would take false positives/not perfect error prevention over ugly unrecoverable errors. The bar for 'just good enough' isn't set very high in these circumstances.

Comment: The correct thing to do in an OOM is to let the process die and be restarted by the watchdog - because you do have something (e.g. systemd) monitoring your production process for crashes right? It would just bite you eventually if you don't, probably on a Friday night. I go a step further and have my server process kill itself once a day, this ensures the watchdog is working correctly, and bad states are cleaned up like fragmented memory.